# Boost regex on windows C++ code::blocks

Tags: c++, regex, boost, linker, boost-regex

I want to use boost regex in c++ on code::blocks on windows. I compile a simple program which uses the instruction `regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );` and it doesn't work, I get errors like: `c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.5.2\..\..\..\..\include\boost\regex\v4\cpp_regex_traits.hpp|366|undefined reference to 'boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'|`

I guess that I should link the project to some lib (.a file ?) in the "linker settings", but I don't know which lib, where can I download it ?!

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile the regular expression library yourself.  Please read the documentation
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html

Comment: There is no an already built boost regex library ? The doc show how to compile it for Visual C++, while I'm using g++/gcc with codeblocks !

Comment: On linux, there are usually pre-compiled boost libraries available as part of the distribution.  On windows you'll probably have to compile it yourself.  You should follow the GCC instructions http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html#boost_regex.install.gcc_2_95_and_later_

Comment: More compilation info for windows here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: This answer explains how to build Boost with Windows & MinGW, and where to find the libraries afterwards: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256788/building-boost-1-52-with-mingw/13257930#13257930 (don't forget to add MinGW's binaries directory to the Windows PATH environment variable beforehands)