# Building Boost 1.52 with MinGW

Tags: boost, mingw

I am trying to find an authorative answer on how to build *Boost 1.52* with *MinGW*. I found some pointers in the Internet that boil down to build it like so:

```
cd tools\build\v2\engine
build.bat mingw

copy bin.ntx86\bjam.exe ..\..\..\..
cd ..\..\..\..
bjam --toolset=gcc
```

Since those instructions date back as far as for *Boost 1.45* and since I couldn't verify this with Boost's own instructions I'd like to verify if the steps above are the correct ones to build Boost with MinGW.

I tried these steps myself and it *seemed* to build Boost, however I have not yet done extensive testing (nor would I have a concept to do this).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20265879/1390430

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. However there would have been a simpler, yet identical way; your steps until the bjam call are automatically done by `bootstrap.bat`:

```
C:\boost_1_52_0> bootstrap.bat mingw
Building Boost.Build engine
...
C:\boost_1_52_0> b2 toolset=gcc
```

If not explicitly specified, the libraries will be placed into the `stage\lib` directory, include path is the installation root. To test the installation, you can use the example from [Link Your Program to a Boost Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library).

References: [Installation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html), [Prepare to Use a Boost Library Binary](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary)

Comment: Just did this with `1.53.0` and `mingw-x64` and worked perfectly

Comment: Do you know how to get all built dlls in one folder (possibly stage\lib) if I you only build some dlls? Namely, how should I modify a command like this: `b2 filesystem system regex program_options variant=debug,release toolset=gcc link=shared -j 7`

Comment: Ok, I answer my own question: instead of listing the project like that, use: `b2 --with-filesystem --with-system --with-regex --with-program_options variant=debug,release toolset=gcc link=shared -j 7`

Comment: Antonio, have you successfully linked to your libs build this way?

Comment: It's been `b2`, not `bjam`, for several years (though, for a while, bjam was still supported for backwards-compatibility with old user scripts; I'm unsure whether it still is as of v1.54.0, mind you; the above worked perfectly for me on that version with my edit in place.)

Comment: The only answer the works for me after searching for hundreds of pages in web! Thanks :D