# How do I build Boost 1.55 with MinGW?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, build, mingw

I have downloaded Boost 1.55 and MinGW.

The console answers me that I haven't any command.
I can't understand how to bind two paths and activate the GCC compiler.

P.S.: If I build boost with Microsoft's compiler I will have about 8 mistakes with error 3861!!

How can I build it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/13256788/1390430

Answer (score 42):

First make sure your mingw's bin directory is in your environment `PATH` so `gcc` and `g++` is callable from your command prompt. Afterwards go into your boost's root directory of where you extracted the files.

Follow that with a bootstrap + b2.exe to build. For example, let's say you only want to compile the regex portion of boost. The follow commands should do the trick:

```
bootstrap gcc
b2 toolset=gcc regex
```

You can use:

```
b2 --show-libraries
```

to get a listing of modules you can build individually. Of course you can build all of them with just:

```
b2 toolset=gcc
```

Check out [Boost Invocation](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation) for a detailed list of available options.

Comment: I had to use `bootstrap gcc`

Comment: @RestlessC0bra this works for me thanks. Using version boost_1_63_0. I add that I found in my project-config.jam file this "using msvc ;" I was confused whether b2 will use msvc to compile sources, however by defining toolset=gcc all works fine and boost is compiled with gcc from mingw.

Answer (score 20):

Greatwolf's answer didn't work for me, so here's how I managed to get it working.

First, make sure `MinGW\bin` is on your path

Go to the `tools\build\v2` directory of your boost folder. For example, in my case it was `C:\Boost\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2`. Then run

```
bootstrap mingw
```

After that, switch to the root Boost directory (this part is important since b2 detects what to build based on current directory)

Now, if you want to build Filesystem, do

```
tools\build\v2\b2 toolset=gcc --build-type=complete stage --with-filesystem
```

This will put `libboost_filesystem-mgw48-d-1_55.dll` etc. in `stage\lib`. If you want to build everything, just leave off the `--with-filesystem` part.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to build it following the instructions from Antimony. However I initially got this error:

```
Bootstrapping the build engine
\Windows was unexpected at this time.
```

The error was solved by clearing the PATH variable and putting just the MinGW folder in it:

```
set PATH=C:\MinGW\bin
```

Then Antimony's instructions did the job for me. Thanks!!

Just two other small things that might be helpful. BOOST for MinGW should be build from the Windows shell, not from the MSYS shell. And in version 1.57 the bootstrap.bat script is no longer in tools\build\v2, but directly in tools\build.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed MinGW/GCC as part of [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net), you will have a "MinGW Command Prompt" that you can launch. This loads a command prompt window and puts the GCC compiler on the PATH for that window. (Similar to the "Developer Command Prompt" that is installed with Visual Studio.)

I think that [the "MinGW distro"](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) comes with one too.

If you have an integrated command prompt you can simply:

- Launch "MinGW Command Prompt"
- Go to your Boost folder (e.g. C:/Boost)
- Run `bootstrap gcc`
- Run `b2 toolset=gcc` (or whatever `b2` command you need)

---

If you are working from examples where someone is not explicitly setting the toolset, you will have to add `toolset=gcc` yourself. Note that `toolset` must be placed in the *property* position not the *option* or *command* position. From `b2 --help`:

```
b2 [options] [properties] [install|stage]
```

So if someone was writing the command to invoke the `install` command with the `--prefix` option, they'd write it as:

```
b2 --prefix=C:\boost-build install
```

And you'd re-write it as:

```
b2 --prefix=C:\boost-build toolset=gcc install
```

See `b2 --help` for more details.