# How do I build boost 1.55 from the command line with mingw?

Tags: boost, command-line, mingw

**Note:** I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265879/how-to-build-boost-1-55-with-mingw) SO question, but I do not think the question is clear and the solutions do not cover the issue I have run into.

I downloaded boost 1.55 from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/) and unzipped it to C:\My Programs\ directory.  When I tried to run the bootstrap.bat file ([REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256788/building-boost-1-52-with-mingw)) I got the error:

```
C:\Users\pollexb\git_repositories\modular-boost>bootstrap.bat 
Building Boost.Build engine 
'"VCVARS32.BAT"' is not recognized as an internal or external command 
operable program or batch file. 
'"VCVARS32.BAT"' is not recognized as an internal or external command 
operable program or batch file. 
'"VCVARS32.BAT"' is not recognized as an internal or external command 
operable program or batch file. 
'"VCVARS32.BAT"' is not recognized as an internal or external command 
operable program or batch file. 
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 

Failed to build Boost.Build engine. 
Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics. 

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from 

   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941 

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org 
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.
```

**What is the problem & how do I solve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost 1.55 seems to have an issue with bootstrap.bat working ([REF](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/bootstrap-bat-broken-for-MinGW-since-1-55-td4655733.html)). The easiest solution would be to download & install [Boost 1.54](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.54.0/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question 2 years later because I had the same issue with boost 1.60.

It looks like you don't have Visual Studio installed. Apparently bootstrap.bat assumes you have that as default, otherwise you should indicate the compiler toolchain you want to use. As an example I had to enter "boostrap.bat **mingw**".